# Understanding a skeleton of jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

At [a website](http://doctype.tv/plugin), I found the following code to make a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){
  // Our code here...
})(jQuery);
```

I don't understand how the code above works. What I understand is that the code executes immediately because the very last `()` in `function(){}()`. So the entire code says that is an anonymous function that is run immediately.

But I don't understand why the wrapping needs to pass `jQuery` and that inside it needs `$` to be passed.

From my understanding, `$` is an alias to `jQuery`, meaning practically the same. What is the meaning of `$` and `jQuery` here? How does the overall code work as a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is the actual parameter. $ is the formal parameter. You could very well write:

```
(function(ForAFewDollarsLess){
    ForAFewDollarsLess('#myId') ...
})(jQuery);
```

One reason is convenience - it's short. You might be using jQuery in noConflict mode with other libraries. Maybe typing `jQuery` all the time is a hassle, or other plugins are following bad practices and using `$` instead of `jQuery`. Either ways, you can use a self-calling function like the one above to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the alias `$` in function so that it will always refter to JQuery actually. If there are some other libraries included in a certain page such as prototype which also uses `$`, your code won't break and will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be maximally compatible with other libraries as well, jQuery offers [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).  This removes the `$` alias from the global namespace so another library could use it if you want.

If you don't want your plugin to work with `.noConflict()` it's not necessary.

Using the closure also allows you to not pollute the "global scope" with `var`'s

Answer (score 0):

Gnarf brought up global scope pollution of vars, I would add of functions as well.

You might want to use a helper function like:

```
(function($){
  // Our code here...
  $.fn.myPluginFunction = function () {
    ...
    var x = foobalizeTheFrobmaster(this.offset())
    ...
  }

  function foobalizeTheFrobmaster(pos) {
    // do something useful
    return something;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

This way the internal function `foobalizeTheFrobmaster()` is completely hidden in our closure.