# Why every jquery plugin is wrapped with (function($) {})(jQuery);

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

every time when I see a jQuery plugin like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.example = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
           return 'Example!';
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

I am wondering about the wrapping function:

```
(function($) {
   // ...
})(jQuery);
```

Is it necessary? If yes, why? And if not, what are the alternatives/advantages?

Comment: Have a look at: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding a skeleton of jQuery plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461049/understanding-a-skeleton-of-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done this way to ensure the plugin is in its own scope and doesn't interfere with anything.

A lot of libraries use `$` as their shortcut, so we're passing `jQuery` and assigning it as `$` to make sure it doesn't interfere.

jQuery explains its use in their docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: There we go. I was waiting for you to answer. Add the link to your answer as well and I'll give you a +1. :)

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Rocket's comment.  From http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring :

> But wait! Where's my awesome dollar sign that I know and love? It's
>   still there, however to make sure that your plugin doesn't collide
>   with other libraries that might use the dollar sign, it's a best
>   practice to pass jQuery to a self executing function (closure) that
>   maps it to the dollar sign so it can't be overwritten by another
>   library in the scope of its execution.

This also helps to [respect the global namespace](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/10/respecting-javascript-global-namespace.html) / prevent global namespace pollution.  Unless you try to - by assigning something to `window`, for example - any variables you create will be kept local to your function - and you don't need to worry about naming conflicts with any other code - in other jQuery plugins or otherwise - including the use of `$`.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically done to give plugin the closure where $ sign doesnt collides with rest of the libraries used along side.